# Plug Sentry on ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: sentry, activemq-artemis

I want to show the metrics of ActiveMQ(messages arriving in the EXPIRY_QUEUE and DL_QUEUE) on Sentry and generate the Alerts using Sentry.

Kindly suggest any option to scrape the ActiveMQ metrics in Sentry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/metrics.html) notes:

> Apache ActiveMQ Artemis can export metrics to a variety of monitoring systems via the [Micrometer](https://micrometer.io/) vendor-neutral application metrics facade.

However, the Micrometer website does not list Sentry as a supported integration. I'm not familiar with Sentry, but if it can deal with formats from other platforms (e.g. [Prometheus](https://github.com/jbertram/artemis-prometheus-metrics-plugin)) then you could make it work. Otherwise you'll likely have to write your own plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. for me, I'm trying to test the sentry plugin for Artemis mq to see if we can raise alerts in Sentry when messages arrive in the EXPIRY_QUEUE and DL_QUEUE

Comment: What "sentry plugin" do you mean?

Comment: plugin that allows you to export metrics ActiveMQ to Sentry

Comment: Does this plugin already exist or are you trying to create it?

Comment: I tried to find a plugin but does not exist

Comment: I added a bit to my answer to try to clarify. In short, you'll likely have to write your own plugin.

Comment: Thanks Justin! It is clear to me now.